# Convert "column = null" to "column is null"?

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, null, oracle10g

I have a simple stored procedure that is dynamically obtaining values from a cursor.  The issue is that at various points some of the bound values can be NULL.
I'd like to be able to use these bound values in another query later, for example:

```
select * from table
where column = value;
```

The issue is that the `value` is NULL which breaks the query.  I realize I need to do a `where column is null` and in the past I've created dynamic queries after evaluating the value.

How can I simply do this comparison to cover both a NULL value and a populated VARCHAR2 value?

Comment: SQL-99 addresses this with "a IS NOT DISTINCT FROM b", not supported in 10g, I believe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One straightforward solution is:

```
where ((value is null     and column is null) or
       (value is not null and column = value))
```

You might like to make sure that indexes on column are actually on (column,0) so that null values are included (and the optimiser knows that they are included).

Comment: Thanks for the comment regarding the index.  We had this problem in the past and created a function-based index for just this reason.  http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_null_idx.htm

Comment: Concerning that article: it's not a "new syntax" for 11g, it's the regular function-based index syntax from 8i. ANSI Coalesce() is better than Nvl() -- often faster due to short-circuit evaluation, and it accepts more than two arguments. The fourth create index example has invalid syntax -- letter  "o" instead of 0, withou quotes around it. Statistics have automatically been gathered on indexes during creation for quite a few versions, so no need to run that separately. You don't need to use a hint to get a function-based index used, and in fact a hint doesn't "force" anything. Not impressive.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `NULL` values to compare as equals:

```
select *
from table
where (column = value or column is null and value is null);
```

Comment: I had the `column = value or column is null` and realized it wasn't correct.  It didn't even dawn on my to also check that the value is null.  Straightforward and easy.  Thanks!

Comment: Congrats on your 100k, Gordon!  :)

Answer (score 0):

`where (column is null) OR (column = value)` perhaps?

Comment: This could potentially grab unintended values in a stored procedure where I don't have control over the inputs during execution.

Answer (score 0):

Use NVl(value,'value to assign if null')

this is oracle specific.